# Move one word backward repeatedly using ESC + B

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I want to be able to move one word backward repeatedly using `ESC + B` on my OSX bash.

The trouble is that I can just hold the `ESC` key and press `B` repeatedly in order to move repeatedly: if I don't re-type the `ESC` key and type `B`, it will type `b` into the bash.

I find it awkward to have to re-type both the `ESC` and the `B` keys in order to repeat...

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `alt+[left/right] arrow` insted :).